# How to input a character in character array using loop in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

what I want to do is input characters in character array in loop .I am new to c programming and don't know uses of pointers very well.my input is something like this :

```
INPUT:
a b
c d
e f upto n times
```

I have declared two arrays `char a[n],b[n];` and I want to input a in `a[0]`, b in `b[1]`, c in `a[2]`...

Here is my attempt

```
char a[n],b[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  scanf("%c %c",&a[i],&b[i]);
  printf("%c %c",*(a+i),*(b+i));
}
```

but this doesn't work!!if I input:  a b  the output is a a 
 `

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a bit vague. What happens? What does it display?

Comment: Now its working but the output and input have one extra line in between. but I haven't used any newline character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run your code I get

```
a b
a bc d

 c  d
```

which means, that the enter you press after each line, will be interpreted as an input character by `scanf()`, since you told her to read characters. Also, I had `n = 3`, but the loop run twice, which also supports this idea.

You should change your `scanf()` to this:

```
scanf(" %c %c",&a[i],&b[i]);
```

which will eat the newline.

Here is a minimal example:

```
int main(void) {
  int n = 3;
  int i;
  char a[n],b[n];
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    scanf(" %c %c",&a[i],&b[i]);
    printf("%c %c\n",*(a+i),*(b+i));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a b
a b
c d
c d
```

The newline in `printf()` is just for formatting elegance, not something more, like a comment had wrongly suggested.

If you want, you can read my page:

[Caution when reading char with scanf (C)](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/)

Comment: You are welcome @user3654540, I see you got down-voted, but I think this is something a person who has never sees it can't easily deal with, so I am upvoting you.

Answer (score 0):

`%c` does not skip newlines.  So your second `scanf` will first read the newline at the end of the first line instead of the 'c'.

You could change the `scanf` to `scanf("%1s %1s", &a[i], &b[i]);` but then you'll have to increase the size of the arrays by one.